# Delphi XE4 + Indy TCP server : large number of threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, tcp

Windows service has multiple permanent TCP connections, accepting data, processing it in separate thread, periodically sending updates to all connected clients. Processing have to be done as realtime as possible, clients are sending one message every 2-4 seconds.

When working with 1900 connections the service has approx 1970 threads. Fine until now. But as total number of threads exceeds 2000-2200 things become strange - sometimes processing thread is blocked without a reason for 10 seconds, even when using realtime priority. In 10 s incoming queue fills up with thousands of requests, so even one second delay is unacceptable. Tried using TSchedulerOfThread to limit number of threads, but in reality this only limits number of connections...

I know Indy consumes one thread per TCP connection. So I've tested Overbyte ICS, which uses  windows messaging (not exactly fan of this, but have no real choice). Thread count is significantly lower (still 70, but that's fine) , working fine also with 3000 connections. For few hours, then service crashes randomly without call stack (madExcept is in use). Only a record in windows event log marked as "application crash".

So neither Indy or ICS works perfectly for me.

Is there any solution in the middle ? I can afford using 1000 threads, but not 3000...

Comment: Is your app 32 or 64 bits? Because on 32 bits, 2000 threads will consume almost whole available memory for 32 bit process for stacks only.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. It is 64bit.

Comment: AFAIK there isnt any hard limit on number of threads per process, especially on 64 bits. So most probably performance effects you see on your system is based on some limit of other system resources, maybe available physical memory, number of cores, or other heavy processes.

Comment: Currently the service is running on Intel Xeon Gold 5218, 64 cores, 128 GB ram. Service working set is 230 MB, so HW should not be an issue. Overall utilization of CPU is under 20%. The strange thing is that even with 2200 threads it may run flawlessly for few days without a problem, or there could be app hung every few hours. Didn't manage to find the rule...

Comment: if the service crash after few hours, it is likely an issue with freeing resources at some point. Use task manager to monitor memory, handles, threads, GDI objects. Difficult to help you without seeing your code. If you need help with ICS, use the dedicated forum: https://en.delphipraxis.net/forum/37-ics-internet-component-suite/

Comment: @Dusan Yes, HW should not be the problem in your case. Just a long shot - it could be a problem of sync code between the threads, if you say sometimes it hangs for 10+ seconds, some kind of racing conditions for common resource if you have such. Also it could be caused by a ineffective low level code generated by Delphi compiler, XE4 is rather old (especially for 64b), they have done a lot of improvements in code generation in latest versions, it would be worth trying compile your service with newer version and see how it is on heavy load.

Comment: One more observation : TCP threads are working normally. But thread doing all the heavy work (processing thread) finishes work set and it should restart loop in 5 ms. But that's not the case. Sometimes like OS is blocking this thread for 30 seconds. Then it runs few times normally and stops again for 10-30 seonds AFTER processing loop is finished.

Comment: 2000 "producers" of messages and only one "worker" thread for heavy work, hm, I think it will be better and more reliable to have several "worker" threads, each will grab a message from the queue and do the work. In that case your working process will not stop when one of worker threads freeze for some reason (unless that problem spans over all "worker" threads).

Comment: @Dusan one more thing - what you mean by "processing loop" and "restart loop"? Isnt your worker thread just waits for new messages to comes in some internal queue, do the work and then waits for next message?

Comment: Messages must be processed in same order as they arrived, there's no option to have more than one worker thread.

By worker thread I mean 

while () do begin
 sleep(5)
 log start of loop
... fetch messages from queue, process them
 log end of work
end

There is log entry "end of work", but then instead of 5 ms it takes 10, sometimes 30 seconds to find another log entry "start of work". And incoming queue reaches 30000 records in between

Comment: 'while () do begin sleep(5)' noooooooooooo!

Answer (score 0):

According to additional info in comments, most probably problems come from `Sleep()` of your worker thread, by documentation of `Sleep()`:

> After the sleep interval has passed, the thread is ready to run. If you specify 0 milliseconds, the thread will relinquish the remainder of its time slice but remain ready. Note that a ready thread is not guaranteed to run immediately.

I think the thread scheduler in Windows doesn't cope well with so many threads, and most probably after your `Sleep(5)`, Windows is still busy with switching between other threads. Also, if you receive 1000 messages per second, even that 5 ms sleep is a lot of time.

In such scenarios, we always use `TThreadedQueue` (not sure if it's available in your version of Delphi) and `PushItem()`/`PopItem()` for producer/consumer transfer of data. You don't need to put your thread to sleep, because "PopItem()`waits for a new message to arrive in the queue (it uses internal logic with a`TMonitor` sync). Our worker threads look like this:

```
while not Terminated do
begin
  FMsg := MsgQueue.PopItem;  //ThreadQueue waits (for PopTimeout) here for item to appears
  if Assigned(FMsg) then
  begin
    AddLogDebug('Begin DoProcessMsg');
    DoProcessMsg;
    AddLogDebug('End DoProcessMsg');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: In single run worker thread fetches all messages from incoming queue (TList of pointers to data structures) and processes them one by one without any delay. And I made mistake, thread is sleeping 1 ms if there a no messages on queue. But for sure it is definitely worth making a test with TTreadQueue and avoiding sleep. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Dusan Btw, about your requirement to process messages in order of received requests - there is still option to use many worker threads, because in synced Queue (like TThreadedQueue) it is guaranteed that messages will come out from queue in the order they get in, but ofc in parallel workers it is possible processing of later item to finish first, but start of processing will be in the exact order, this could be used to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately multiple worker threads are out of question... because the result of next calculation depends on previous and no parallel processing is possible.

In the meantime I updated Overbyte ICS and ran tests during weekend, looks much better now. The only thins that worries me is possibility of memory leak. But first I have to exclude my faule